# How having schedule AND push/pull_request events in a GitHub workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to run a workflow if a push/pull_request events is trigger **OR** when a schedule event is trigger...

Here my broken (syntax issue) `.github/workflows/docker.yml`:

```yaml
name: Docker

on: [push, pull_request]
  schedule:
    # min hours day(month) month day(week)
    - cron: '0 0 */5 * *'

...
```

Unfortunately this syntax is wrong, here the error:

```
Invalid workflow file
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the doc:

> **Example using multiple events with activity types or configuration**
> If you need to specify activity types or configuration for an event, you must configure each event separately. You must append a colon (:) to all events, including events without configuration.

ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-multiple-events-with-activity-types-or-configuration

So here we can't use a list of events...

```yaml
name: Docker

on: 
  push:
  pull_request:
  schedule:
    # min hours day(month) month day(week)
    - cron: '0 0 */5 * *'

...
```